# Javascript Canvas With Background Image - Eraser Tool

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am attempting to develop a drawing tool using Canvas and JavaScript. Unfortunately, I'm facing difficulties in implementing an eraser tool. The canvas background is not static as I intend to use it for masking purposes, where the background is black and the lines are white. Can you provide assistance on how to achieve this?

```
 <script>

    let strokeValue = 0;
    document.getElementById("strokeRange").addEventListener("input", function (event) {
        strokeValue = document.getElementById("strokeRange").value;
        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = strokeValue;
        context.lineWidth = strokeValue;
    });

    document.getElementById("eraserCheckbox").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
            context.strokeStyle = "?????";
        } else {
            context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
        }
    })


    "use strict";
    var context = document.getElementById('sheet').getContext("2d");
    var canvas = document.getElementById('sheet');
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "https://www.brettonwoodsproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/512px-Rembrandt_Christ_in_the_Storm_on_the_Lake_of_Galilee-1.jpg";

    // Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
    background.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(background,0,0);   
    }


    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


    context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = strokeValue;

    
    var clickX = [];
    var clickY = [];
    var clickDrag = [];
    var paint;

    /**
     * Add information where the user clicked at.
     * @param {number} x
     * @param {number} y
     * @return {boolean} dragging
     */
    function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
        clickX.push(x);
        clickY.push(y);
        clickDrag.push(dragging);
    }

    /**
     * Redraw the complete canvas.
     */
    function redraw() {
        // Clears the canvas
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(background,0,0); 

    }

    /**
     * Draw the newly added point.
     * @return {void}
     */
    function drawNew() {
        var i = clickX.length - 1
        if (!clickDrag[i]) {
            if (clickX.length == 0) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                context.stroke();
            } else {
                context.closePath();

                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                context.stroke();
            }
        } else {
            context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    function mouseDownEventHandler(e) {
        paint = true;
        var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        if (paint) {
            addClick(x, y, false);
            drawNew();
        }
    }

    function touchstartEventHandler(e) {
        paint = true;
        if (paint) {
            addClick(e.touches[0].pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - canvas.offsetTop, false);
            drawNew();
        }
    }

    function mouseUpEventHandler(e) {
        context.closePath();
        paint = false;
    }

    function mouseMoveEventHandler(e) {
        var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        if (paint) {
            addClick(x, y, true);
            drawNew();
        }
    }

    function touchMoveEventHandler(e) {
        if (paint) {
            addClick(e.touches[0].pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - canvas.offsetTop, true);
            drawNew();
        }
    }

    function setUpHandler(isMouseandNotTouch, detectEvent) {
        removeRaceHandlers();
        if (isMouseandNotTouch) {
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEventHandler);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveEventHandler);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownEventHandler);
            mouseDownEventHandler(detectEvent);
        } else {
            canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartEventHandler);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMoveEventHandler);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchend', mouseUpEventHandler);
            touchstartEventHandler(detectEvent);
        }
    }

    function mouseWins(e) {
        setUpHandler(true, e);
    }

    function touchWins(e) {
        setUpHandler(false, e);
    }

    function removeRaceHandlers() {
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseWins);
        canvas.removeEventListener('touchstart', touchWins);
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseWins);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', touchWins);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with image as css background setting like code below. I also have used globalCompositeOperation to make erasing possible.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const pr = window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth * pr;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight * pr;

ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f33';

const config = {erase: false, started: false};
const pos = (e) => {
  return [e.offsetX * pr, e.offsetY * pr];
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  config.erase = e.shiftKey;
  config.started = true;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = config.erase ? 'destination-out' : 'source-over';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(...pos(e));
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  config.started = false;
  ctx.closePath();
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (config.started){
    ctx.lineTo(...pos(e));
    ctx.stroke();
  }
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px #999 solid;
  background-image: url("https://www.brettonwoodsproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/512px-Rembrandt_Christ_in_the_Storm_on_the_Lake_of_Galilee-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

(draw with mouse, shift + mouse to erase)

There is another one solution exist if you `need` to use canvas image drawing. In this case you can store drawn pixels and redraw on erasing - just delete particular pixels from draw matrix and redraw canvas from background. This approach is much more complex and has lower performance but can be more flexible on canvas resize.